# Groovy conditional simple logic in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In the Jenkins pipeline, a simple "if" condition is not working.

The "if" condition is in groovy. And if the action is "Plan", the if condition is getting skipped. any suggestion how to do if condition in groovy?

```groovy
stage('Terraform PLAN') {
    dir(Code_Path) {
         container('terraform') {
             if ("$Action" == "Plan") {
                  sh '''
                     echo "the action is Plan"
                  '''
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple if else is just like this even in groovy scripts:

```js
if(Flow=="allFlows")
return ["Regression Testing", "Smoke Testing", "Sanity Testing"]
else
return ["Current Tag", "Tagless"]
```

Could you kindly elaborate what you are trying to achieve?